# ¿Cómo puedo resolver este error en Visual Studio al usar whisper y pytube?

Tags: python

estoy intentando transcribir el audio de un vídeo de youtube con la IA de whisper con el siguiente código:

```
import pytube
import whisper

youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a419iZMeN0o&ab_channel=SinEmbargoAlAire"
youtubeVideo = pytube.YouTube(youtubeUrl)

audio = youtubeVideo.streams.get_audio_only()
audio.download(filename='tmp.mp4')

model = whisper.load_model("small")
result = model.transcribe('tmp.mp4')

print(result['text'])
```

El problema es que me arroja el siguiente respuesta:

> PSC:\Users\fenix.vscode>&C:/Users/fenix/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe"c:/Users/fenix/.vscode/import pytube.py"
> Traceback (most recent call
> last):
> File "c:\Users\fenix.vscode\import pytube.py", line 2, in
>
> import whisper
> File "C:\Users\fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\whisper.py",
> line 69, in 
> libc = ctypes.CDLL(libc_name)
> File "C:\Users\fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py",
> line 364, in **init**
> if '/' in name or '\' in name:
> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

¿Saben qué estoy haciendo mal? Ya instalé whisper, pytube, dentro de del GIT del chico menciona que también necesitas el ffmpeg, también lo instalé, aun que el ejemplo que vi no lo mencionaba.

Comment: pudistes resolver el problema? me paso lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Es porque para funcionar, también requiere que la herramienta de línea de comandos ffmpeg esté instalada en su sistema, que está disponible en la mayoría de los administradores de paquetes:

#### on Ubuntu or Debian

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

#### on Arch Linux

```
sudo pacman -S ffmpeg
```

#### on MacOS using Homebrew (https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

#### on Windows using Chocolatey (https://chocolatey.org/)

```
choco install ffmpeg
```

#### on Windows using Scoop (https://scoop.sh/)

```
scoop install ffmpeg
```

Comment: para eso tambien tienes que installar scoop o choco si trabajas con windows, que son herramientas que te permiten instalar paquetes.
se puede hacer asi:
> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser # Optional: Needed to run a remote script the first time

> irm get.scoop.sh | iex